# Read file using a buffer in c

Tags: c, file, io

This is my code where fp is the opened file

```
unsigned char string[10];
while(fgets(string, 10, fp))
    // do stuff with string
```

Now i want to loop each char in the array but how is the array filled when the file only had 5 characters. Does it contain an EOF char or something?

Comment: `EOF` is not a character. That's actually the idea behind it.

Comment: fgets will get the specified number of characters or until it finds an EOF or newline character. Source: http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fgets/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From [`fgets()`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/fgetc.3.html):

> fgets() reads in at most one less than size characters from stream 
>   and stores them into the buffer pointed to by s. Reading stops after 
>   an EOF or a newline. If a newline is read, it is stored into the 
>   buffer. A terminating null byte ('\0') is stored after the last 
>   character in the buffer.

That means if your file contains only 5 chars in a single line (i.e. assuming no more than one newline),
then `string` will contain 5 chars and the 6th byte in `string` will be the terminating null byte.

To loop over it, you can use:

```
for(i = 0; string[i]; i++) { //until the terminating byte
    char ch = string[i];
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

the string is stored in array from 0 - the length and ends with \0
so you can make use of the \0 in looping or accessing each string

```
   char string[100] //
    for(i=0;string[i]!=\0;i++) // looping until I becomes \0
        {
        ch=string[i];
        }
```